# function to find an element inside the array

Tags: javascript, function

I wrote a function to find an element inside the array. Because the types of arrays are different`(ex:Array1,Array1,Array1,Array1)`, I had a problem with part `arr.map(el => el + "." + n)`, and for my arrays this part must be defined in this way for the function to work.

```
Array1     =>arr.map(el => el.fullName)
Array2     =>arr.map(el => el.Name)
Array3     =>arr.map(el => el.sName)
Array3     =>arr.map(el => el.sameName)
```

Friends, can you help me how to solve the problem?

```
function findNameInArray(arr, name, n) {
    let names = arr.map(el => el + "." + n);
    let num = names.indexOf(name);
    let ch = arr[num];
    return ch
}

Array1 =[{fullName:"name1",snumber:1},{fullName:"name2",snumber:2}];
Array2 =[{Name:"name1",number:1},{Name:"name2",number:2}];
Array3 =[{sName:"name1",snumber:1},{sName:"name2",snumber:2}];
Array4 =[{sameName:"name1",number:1},{sameName:"name2",number:2}];
```

Comment: Either I am not understanding this or you are re-inventing the wheel: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find

Comment: [`findIndex`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex). What is the code supposed to do? What’s the expected result?

Comment: Dude, what are you trying to achieve here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the code in the question it looks like you really just checking to see if the name *exists* in the array of objects. You don't need to return the name from the function because you already know what it is.

You can create a function that passes in the array, the name, and the object property that needs to be evalauted, and then use [`some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) to make that evaluation. The function will return a boolean (either true or false).

```js
function nameExists(arr, name, prop) {
  return arr.some(obj => obj[prop] === name);
}

const arr = [{fullName:'name1',snumber:1},{fullName:'name2',snumber:2}];
const arr2 = [{sName:'name1',snumber:1},{sName:'name3',snumber:2}];
const arr3 = [{sameName:"name1",number:1},{sameName:"name2",number:2}];
const arr4 = [{sameName:"name1",number:1},{sameName:"Bob",number:2}];

console.log(nameExists(arr, 'name2', 'fullName'));
console.log(nameExists(arr2, 'Bob', 'sName'));
console.log(nameExists(arr3, 'name2', 'sameName'));
console.log(nameExists(arr4, 'Bob', 'job'));
```